# Write unit test for trait in model laravel

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, traits

I've written a trait for auto adding some closure model events to model which use this trait.
This is my code:

```php
trait WatchCardListChange
{
  public static function booted()
  {
    static::watchCardListChange();
  }

  protected static function watchCardListChange()
  {
    $modelClass = get_called_class();
    $classParts = explode('\\', $modelClass);
    $className = end($classParts);
    $method = 'addEventsTo' . $className . 'Model';
    forward_static_call([$modelClass, $method]);
  }

  private static function addEventsToAcCardModel()
  {
    static::created(function ($model) {
      CardListChanged::dispatch($model);
    });
    static::updated(function ($model) {
      CardListChanged::dispatch($model);
    });
    static::deleted(function ($model) {
      CardListChanged::dispatch($model);
    });
  }
}
```

I've searched for writing unit test for this test which use [getMockForTrait](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/test-doubles.html#mocking-traits-and-abstract-classes) and this is my code:

```php
public function test_trait()
{
  // First approach
  $mock = $this->partialMock(AcCard::class, function (MockInterface $mock) {
    $mock->shouldAllowMockingProtectedMethods()->shouldReceive('booted')->once();
  });
  app()->instance(AcCard::class, $mock);
  $model = new AcCard();

  // Second approach
  $trait = $this->getMockForTrait(WatchCardListChange::class, [], '', true, true, true, ['watchCardListChange']);
  $trait->expects(self::exactly(1))->method('watchCardListChange');

  // Test
  $model = AcCard::factory()->create();
}
```

But both of 2 approaches seem not work.

I wonder what is the best practice to test this trait? Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Try using mocking framework [Mockery](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/cookbook/mocking_hard_dependencies.html); the technique is overloading a class /methods:

```
use Mockery as m;
...

m::mock('overload:Full\Namespace\To\WatchCardListChange', function ($mock) {
   $mock->shouldReceive('watchCardListChange')
        ->once()
        ->andReturn(whatever);
})->shouldIgnoreMissing();
```

This will go ahead a create a mock in-place; now you can test static call however you want; You can even mock something inside the function itself and when it being called mock object will returned value will be replaced in-place.

Comment: Using `overload` can solve problem that method `watchCardListChange` asserts run `once`. But I still don't know how to test other method in my trait. Besides, mock object from code block above return an mock object while `WatchCardListChange` is declared to be a trait